# When user allow using photo I can't see any thing in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, photo

I have collection view with Images of photo library But there is a problem just for first time that user Allows using photos - when the app runs for the first time and user allows to use photos the user can't see anyImages and should dismiss that view controller and come back again to see the Images

here is the codes :

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class typeandtranslateViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  , UITextFieldDelegate {


static var checkTextField = Bool()

@IBOutlet var backgroundimg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var frontimg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var typeView: UIView!

let arr_img = NSMutableArray()
let arr_selected = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var collview: UICollectionView!


@IBOutlet weak var sefareshTitleTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func caneraButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera ;

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker,animated: true , completion: nil)
    }

    print("Camera!")


}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage,self,nil,nil)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("save Image ")



}
@IBOutlet weak var viewCamera: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    print("Text Field Condition ")

    if sefareshTitleTextField!.text! == "" {

        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = false


        print("sefaresh title is nill")
    } else if sefareshTitleTextField!.text! != "" {


        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = true
        print("sefaresh title isnt nill")

    }

    self.sefareshTitleTextField.delegate = self


    collview?.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    let allPhotosOptions : PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.init()
    allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
    let allPhotosResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: allPhotosOptions)
    allPhotosResult.enumerateObjects({ (asset, idx, stop) in

        self.arr_img.add(asset)

    })


    self.typeView.layer.cornerRadius = self.typeView.frame.size.height/50
    self.typeView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.typeView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.typeView.clipsToBounds = true


    self.viewCamera.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.viewCamera.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.viewCamera.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.viewCamera.clipsToBounds = true


    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true


    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurView.frame =  CGRect(x: self.backgroundimg.frame.origin.x, y: self.backgroundimg.frame.origin.y, width: self.backgroundimg.frame.size.width, height: self.backgroundimg.frame.size.height)

    blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.backgroundimg.addSubview(blurView)

}

func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset, size: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let retinaScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let retinaSquare = CGSize(width: size * retinaScale, height: size * retinaScale)//CGSizeMake(size * retinaScale, size * retinaScale)
    let cropSizeLength = min(asset.pixelWidth, asset.pixelHeight)
    let square = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cropSizeLength, height: cropSizeLength)//CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(cropSizeLength), CGFloat(cropSizeLength))
    let cropRect = square.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth), y: 1.0/CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)))

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()

    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.resizeMode = .exact
    options.normalizedCropRect = cropRect

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: retinaSquare, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })


    return thumbnail
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true);

    if sefareshTitleTextField!.text == "" {

        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = false


        print("sefaresh title is nill")
    } else if sefareshTitleTextField!.text! != "" {


        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = true
        print("sefaresh title isnt nill")

    }



    return false;



}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if sefareshTitleTextField!.text! == "" {

        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = false


        print("sefaresh title is nill")
        } else if sefareshTitleTextField!.text! != "" {


        typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = true
        print("sefaresh title isnt nill")

        }

}



//MARK:
//MARK: Collectioview methods


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr_img.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celll",
                                                  for: indexPath)
    let imgview : UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIImageView
    imgview.image = self.getAssetThumbnail(asset: self.arr_img.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PHAsset, size: 150)

    let selectView : UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(22) as! UIImageView
    if arr_selected.contains(indexPath.row){

        selectView.image = UIImage(named: "Select.png")
    }else{

        selectView.image = UIImage(named: "radioCircleButton.png")

    }

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.clipsToBounds = true


    return cell
}

var selectedIndexes = [NSIndexPath]() {
    didSet {
        collview.reloadData()
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{



    if arr_selected.contains(indexPath.row){
        arr_selected.remove(indexPath.row)
    }else{
        arr_selected.add(indexPath.row)
    }

    self.collview.reloadData()

}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = backgroundimg.bounds
    backgroundimg.addSubview(blurView)
    backgroundimg.frame = self.view.bounds
}

@IBAction func backToTheMainCustom(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTheMainCustom", sender: self)

    sefareshTitleTextField!.text! = ""

    typeandtranslateViewController.checkTextField = false
}

}
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: so wait I have to write all of my codes here I will Edit question

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ask user for permissions to access to the photo library. If request happens first time, wait for his answer and open the UIImagePickerController again. Please review the following code:

```
let photosAccess = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
switch photosAccess {
case .notDetermined:
    // First time here. Request the access
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        if status == .authorized{
            // Access was just granted
            // Open library here
        }
    })

case .authorized:
    // Open library here

case .denied, .restricted:
    // Photos access is not granted.
    // Good place to take user to app settings.
}
```

The same about camera:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { response in
    if response {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Show camera UI here
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Access is restricred
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nothin g happened the app still doesn't show library photos when the user allows But in the next times when the user opens the app there is no problem just like before